# Cerrar pestañas de Notebook tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

tengo un programa con TKINTER, donde tengo varias pestañas de un Notebook, y he creado un menú contextual, y una opción es cerrar ventana, lo tengo asociación a una función (sin desarrollar), quiero que esa función, me cierre la pestaña activá, cómo sería posible??

Gracias[image: Mi proyecto como se ve actualmente]

Comment: Hola @nadie y Jhon, gracias por vuestra respuesta. Si he podido revisar la web de recursospython y de hay he podido trabajar con este proyecto, porque la verdad soy nuevo y no he tenido formación, más que lectura en web y tutoriales, y a las respuestas de aquí. Siguiendo con mi proyecto, como veréis en la imagen ya pude implementar en mi proyecto, las X  en los para cerrar, pero al hacer el menú contextual y darle cerrar pestañas, que me llama a una función, el Index de la pestaña no me coge el que es y no sé porque, me cierra la pestaña, pero no en la que estoy, si no la que el Index indica.

Comment: Pero probaré lo que me dices y haber si consigo algo, de todos modos gracias

Comment: Ese comentario debes hacerlo en la respuesta de cada usuario, de esta forma no se enteraran

Comment: A no se cómo se hace, ok lo miro gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retomando su pregunta, si es posible eliminar un `Tab` o pestaña seleccionada, la manera más fácil y viable es usar una función que elimine la pestaña por medio de un botón o una llamada a esa función. Por tanto, en un concepto más complejo se pueden agrupar botones al lado de las pestañas, sin embargo, es más complejo por que se debe crear los estilos.

**Aunque su pregunta se enfoca en una función que elimine la pestaña seleccionada, está es la solución:**

```
def EliminarPestana():
    try:
        PestanaControlSettings.forget("current") # PestanaControlSettings es el control de pestañas inicial o variable del ttk.Notebook()
    except:
        messagebox.showwarning('Control de pestañas', 'Se han eliminado o no existen más pestañas.')
```

> Tenga en cuenta que `PestanaControlSettings` es la variable que utilicé para el `ttk.Notebook()`. Puede llamar esta función por medio un botón. Si se eliminan todas las pestañas del control, generará excepción por lo cual use bloque de excepción `try` y `except` para evitar error.

Comment: Mira los comentarios de la pregunta :)

Comment: Gracias @John, te decía más arriba en un comentario, que sí he conseguido implementar el botón de cerrar en la pestaña, en un respuesta a otra pregunta en esta web, pero lo que quiero ahora es implementar lo mismo desde la llamada de un botón o del menú contextual en mi caso, por medio de una función, lo intente y me sale este error :.    traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
     return self.func(*args)
 TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'e',.

Comment: En la opción del menú, puse , command = lamda e : self.cerrar_pestaña(e), y la funcion está definida como, def cerrar_pestaña(self, event): y me devuelve ese error

Comment: Si es un `bind` o evento, es recomendable que el parámetro `event` esté en `None`, sucede porque cuando llama la función, no hay suficientes argumentos para el evento, por lo cual desencadena error, por tanto el argumento de la función debe llamarse bajo el parámetro `event=None` en vez de solo `event`. En este caso `event=None` como atributo sea opcional para que se pueda llamar a la devolución de llamada directamente, aunque si está usando un botón o una entrada de menú `command` en ese caso pasa todos los parámetros dentro de una función anónima y no requeriría `event`.

Comment: Gracias, lo he podido conseguir

Answer (score 2):

Para eso hay dos formas:

> 1. De forma temporal. Con `miNotebook.hide(Unframe)`, para volver a mostrarla
>    `miNotebook.add(Unframe)`.

> 2. De forma permanente. Con `miNotebook.forget(Unframe)`

En ambas operaciones puedes usar index.
De todas maneras no creo que hayas investigado mucho, ya que si lo investigas un poco fácilmente te encuentras esta [web](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/panel-de-pestanas-notebook-tkinter/). Mírala habla bastante de tkinter y aparte de con el notebook también te puede ayudar con otras cosas.

Comment: Mora los comentarios de la pregunta  :)

Comment: Hola @nadie, te decía más arriba en los comentarios, que si he revisado la web de recursospython y de hay he sacado mucha información, y que al hacer miNotebook.hide(Index), si tengo varias pestañas activas y darle al click derecho abrir menú contextual y darle a cerrar pestaña, me cierra la última abierta porque la variable Index me recoge la última pestaña abierta, y no la que tengo activa y no la que estoy actualmente, realizando las actividades necesarias.